# c# parsing xml with and apostrophe throws exception

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

I am parsing an xml file and am running into an issue when trying find a node that has an apostrophe in it.  When item name does not have this everything works fine.  I have tried replacing the apostrophe with different escape chars but am not having much luck

```
string s = "/itemDB/item[@name='" + itemName + "']";

// Things i have tried that did not work
// s.Replace("'", "''");
// .Replace("'", "\'");

XmlNode parent = root.SelectSingleNode(s);
```

I always receive an XPathException. What is the proper way to do this.  Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to accomplish something like this: <XYZ X='Lol"/> where LoL is what you really want?

Comment: Can you give an example of the xml you are trying to parse?

Comment: here is a simple version of what is breaking
<itemDB>
  <item name="abc's cfd"/>
<itemDB>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it Like this:

```
XmlDocument root = new XmlDocument();

root.LoadXml(@"<itemDB><item name=""abc'def""/></itemDB>");

XmlNode node = root.SelectSingleNode(@"itemDB/item[@name=""abc'def""]");
```

Note the verbatim string literal '@' and the double quotes.

Your code would then look like this and there is no need to replace anything:

```
var itemName = @"abc'def";

string s = @"/itemDB/item[@name=""" + itemName + @"""]";
```

Answer (score 4):

For apostophe replace it with `&apos;`

Comment: +1 - There also may be some other characters you need to escape too. http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2008/10/21/Different-ways-how-to-escape-an-XML-string-in-C.aspx

Comment: I tried  s= s.Replace("'", "&apos;"); and this gets me past exception but returns null because it doesn't think its in the xml file. The item name is random.  concatenation is the only way i could think of to select the proper node.  Is there a better way?

Comment: the xml file that I am parsing from is fairly large and i do not have the option to modify it.  the file has something like this in it
<item name="abc's def"/>