# C# cannot save apostrophe to XML

Tags: c#, xml

I tried to save apostrophe ' to XML, but always I get an error.

When I want to save new item, first I tried to find it. I use this

```
XmlNode letters = root.SelectSingleNode("//letters");
XmlNode oldFileLetter = letters.SelectSingleNode("letter[@name='"+letterName+"']");
```

but when `letterName` contains apostrophe ' I get an error, that path isn't closed

I also found this [c# parsing xml with and apostrophe throws exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479066/c-sharp-parsing-xml-with-and-apostrophe-throws-exception) but when I did what Steven said, it's OK for apostrophe, but double quotes throw exception.

I need to pass " and ' too.

Comment: name is a Attribute in Xml right?? If its a attribute it wont support apostrophe

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-xml-document-escape-characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that your XPath already has an apostrophe indicating the beginning of a string within the XPath, so any apostrophe in your letterName value would be interpereted as closing the string value.

Contrary to Felipe's advice, XPaths are not themselves XML, so replacing the apostrophes with `&apos;` will not work.  It will avoid the error, but you won't find the node you're looking for if letterName contains an apostrophe.  Also, there is no difference in C# between `"'"` and `"\'"`, so that will not help either.

I'd suggest looping through the letter elements and identifying the one where @name has the value you're looking for:

```
XmlNode oldFileLetter = null;
foreach(XmlNode letterNameNode in letters.SelectNodes("letter/@name"))
{
    if(letterNameNode.Value.Equals(letterName))
    {
        oldFileLetter = letterNameNode.ParentNode;
        break; 
    }
}
```

The only other approach I know of involves rigging up a system to allow defining and using XPath variables in your paths, but that's usually overkill.

Answer (score 3):

You also could replace the apostriphe by `&apos;`

```
letterName = letterName.Replace("'", "&apos;");

XmlNode letters = root.SelectSingleNode("//letters");
XmlNode oldFileLetter = letters.SelectSingleNode("letter[@name='"+letterName+"']");
```

Take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-xml-document-escape-characters) about special chars on a xml file.

Comment: Thanks, I had this in my code, but later, I save letterName, so saved was "&amp;apos;" so I deleted this. Thank you

Comment: So I have next problem. How to save an apostrophe? Because, when I use replace like you, in file atribute is "&amp;apos;" and during loading, it convert back badly. But when I do `name.InnerText = "'"` to file is saved ' and your code can't find this atribute...

Comment: Yes, when you save with this char `&amp;apos;` and you want to read again to get a valid string in C#, you have to do the inverted step, I mean replace again the `&amp;apos;`  to `'`. If you are on a web project (I'm not sure if it is valid for windows projects), you also can check the `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(string)` and `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(string)` to do this changes, add the reference for `System.Web`. take a look: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h.aspx

Comment: I'm fairly sure, and correct me if I'm wrong, that this will prevent an error from happening, but it will not find the node you are looking for if letterName has an apostrophe in it. SelectSingleNode() will just return null in that situation.

Comment: @JLRishe, yes, you are right. Because I save always only 1 character, I did one ugly stuff. If you want to save apostrophe, xpath is enclosed in quotes otherwise in apostrophes. But for next time, I want to resolve this issue. This answer allow to me save apostrophe, but not to find.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried escaping it as such:

```
\'
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to write it as an entity i think...
I'm,not sure but i can recall having come across this issue once before.

Look at this wikipedia thread...
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Answer (score 0):

```
const string apo = "\'";
XmlNode letters = root.SelectSingleNode("//letters");
XmlNode oldFileLetter = letters.SelectSingleNode("letter[@name="+apo+letterName+apo+"]")
```